# What are Inherited numerable properties?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the definition of **`for...in`**

> The `for...in` statement iterates over all enumerable properties of objects that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.

Now, I do understand what's a numerable property in JavaScript, but this term **"inherited enumerable properties"** is confusing, and I'm not able to understand it clearly.

Comment: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-uses-of-in-vs-hasownproperty.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Example:***

```js
class A{
  constructor(){
  this.name="Sample"
  }
}
class B extends A{
 constructor(){
  super()
  this.planet="earth"
 }
}
let b=new B();
for(let props in b)
    console.log(props)
```

***Explanation:***

**A** has property **name**.
**B** is inheriting the class **A**.
So properties will also get inherited.

`for(let props in objectOfClassB)` will give you instance properties and its inherited properties.

Clear?